# Sharing database connection across fixed number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, thread-safety, threadpool

```
public class Parser {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        public void update() {

            Item item = new Item(subj.getName(), dateBuilder.toString(),
                    cobBuilder.toString(), interest, count);

            pool.submit(new ItemDispatcher(item));
        }



    } 



    public class ItemDispatcher implements Runnable {

        private Item item;

        public ItemDispatcher(Item someItem) {

            this.item = someItem;

        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                new Database(item).writeToDb();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 

            }

        }

    }


    public class Database {

        private String name;
        private String date;
        private String cob;
        private String interest;
        private String count;

        private String _url;
        private String _userId;
        private String _password;
        private String _dbLib;
        private String _dbFile;
        private Connection _conn;
        private PreparedStatement _statement;

        public Database(Item item) {

            name = item.get_item();
            date = item.get_date();
            cob = item.get_cob();
            interest = item.get_interest();
            count = item.get_count();
        }


        public void writeToDb() {

            try {

                //statment.setString(); 
            }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

    }
```

How can I create a db connection that is thread-safe and not initialse a new connection per thread doing tasks. I've asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428512/single-db-connection-that-does-not-get-initialised-per-task) but the solution uses third party library which I am not looking to use. can someone please show me a simple alternative ?

Comment: Make the Class Connection which will provide the connection and make it singleton

Comment: I'm not to sure how to create connection pooling in multi-thread app using singleton :(

Comment: follow this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/588099/java/java/access-Singleton-connection-database

Comment: should the run() method receive the instance and perform the db insertion ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single connection when you create you thread pool

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(...)
```

Then pass it to each ItemDispatcher you create

```
new ItemDispatcher(item, c)
```

Have ItemDispatcher hold it in a member variable.

Finally you'll probably need to protect access to the connection with synchronized blocks

```
synchronized(c) {
    try {
        new Database(item).writeToDb();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to hide the db connection code from the class that creates worker threads

Comment: You can either create a 3rd class which is the "context" and can hold onto the pool and connection, or make a static singleton inside ItemDispatcher an connect to the database the first time it's used.  The context way is cleaner, but more code.  Which is better depends on what you mean by "simple"